# Could be that the dates and timeline of 4 yugas got changed when puranas were passed down orally?

Tags: puranas, yuga, kali-yuga, time, sruti

The durations for yugas are way too large.
Can it be that puranas witnessed contamination or corruption from people who weren't able to calculate the yugas correctly? Or were they exaggerated by later scribes?

What are the different timelines for yugas that different scriptures give?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82718/discussion-on-question-by-anisha-could-be-that-the-dates-and-timeline-of-4-yugas).

Comment: The Chāndogya Upaniṣad (3.16.7)0 mentions a human living for 1,600 years.